# Ionic firestore Cannot find module "@angular/fire/firestore"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

im importing Angularfirestore like this

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

its showing error Error: Cannot find module "@angular/fire/firestore" .

```
"firebase": "^4.13.1",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { firebaseConfig } from './credentials';
```

Comment: please also see this question if you can help thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083491/ionic-firestore-submit-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **You have installed with commands**
>
> ```
> npm install firebase angularfire2
> ```
>
> **The import for AngularFirestore is**
>
> ```
> import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
> ```

**your app.module to have imports like:~**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**you’ll want to inject the AngularFirestore injectable into your component using following imports** :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

**Your `enviornment.ts` can have your firebase config like below:~**

In your case its `import { firebaseConfig } from './credentials';`

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    authDomain: 'your-project-id.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://your-project-id.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'your-project-id',
    storageBucket: 'your-project-id.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
  }
};
```